# Having "Unable to store in SecurityContext" error in Spring application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

I'm developing a Spring MVC web application.

I was not having any problem but after some small changes in my code (not related to the SecurityContext)  I started having this error

> org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository$SaveToSessionResponseWrapper
>   createNewSessionIfAllowed Failed to create a session, as response has
>   been committed. Unable to store SecurityContext.

In my code I've been always able to store an `Authentication` object with this line

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(myAuthentication);
```

Google didn't help me. What is happening? What is that error for?

Comment: have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/a/4823252/525251 ?

Comment: My application uses the SecurityContext to store the authorities for the logged in users, so I cannot make it stateless. Nevertheless, this error came out after a minor change in my code. I thinkk that is not the way to follow

Comment: Can you share the minor change in your code? It seems that something is committing the response (i.e. response.getWriter().flush() ) and Spring Security isn't able to create the HTTP session. You might try updating Spring Security to the latest version to see if this resolves your issue as some related issues have been resolved in newer versions. Alternatively, you can have Spring Security eagerly create the session with <http create-session="always">